# Simple path in a graph, within a given range of lengths

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal

Given an undirected graph $G(V,E)$ and two nodes $s$ and $t$, $s,t\in V$, find a path whose length $L$ is bounded by a lower bound $N$ and an upper bound $M$, $N\leq L\leq M$.

So, for example, $N=4, M=7$, I want to confirm that there is at least one simple path of 4,5,6 and 7 between two nodes in a graph? Nodes of the graph may appear in more than one path.

Typical problem size:

- 10,000 nodes
- Mean of 20 edges per node
- Cycles in graph
- Unweighted edges

Comment: I wonder, don't you already have a practical answer [in your question on CSTheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/20830/5693)?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

A special case of your problem is to determine whether there is a path of length between $n-1$ and $n-1$ (sic) in an $n$-vertex graph. This is the Hamiltonian path problem, which is well known to be **NP**-complete, so your problem is also **NP**-complete. More generally, it's also **NP**-complete to determine if a graph has a path of length at least $k$ (i.e., between $k$ and $n-1$) between two given vertices.

Answer (score 0):

I see this problem pretty close to the target-value search problem:

*Given a graph $G(V,E)$ and a natural number $T$ find the path between the vertices $s, t\in V$ whose cost (or length in case of unary costs) is as close as possible to the given target value $T$*

The latest reference on the question is, as far as I can tell [Target-Value Search Revisited](http://ijcai.org/papers13/Papers/IJCAI13-096.pdf) which was recently published at the International Joint Conference on Artificial Intelligence ---admittedly, this is a paper of my own, sorry for self-referencing my own work but I do see your question closely related to this other one.

Just invoke the target-value search algorithm with a target value equal to the average $T=\lfloor\frac{N+M}{2}\rfloor$ and there you go, it will find the path with the cost closer to it thus solving your problem. There is only a caveat and it is that if $N+M$ is an odd number the algorithm might prefer a solution with a cost equal to $\lfloor\frac{N+M}{2}\rfloor-\lceil\frac{M-N}{2}\rceil$ instead of $M$ (note that the first term is strictly less than $N$ iff $N+M$ is an odd number), but there are various ways to solve this problem efficiently.

Finally, the algorithm pursues paths with a **cost** as close as possible to the given target value $T$. In case you are interested in the **length** instead, then just provide graphs with unary costs.

In case you are interested I can provide you with source code (in C++) that implements target-value search. I made experiments with graphs as those you mention (but shorter branching factors) and it effectively finds optimal solutions pretty fast (in less than a second). Moreover, if you do not mind, I would be happy to make experiments with your domains in case you have any at hand that you could send me.

Hope this helps,